# Connecting to MySQL 5.6 inside Docker For Desktop/Kubernetes: ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host 'xx.xx.xx.xx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, docker-desktop

I'm [following theses instructions](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/kubernetes-up-and/9781492046523/?afsrc=1) (page 181) to create a persistent volume & claim, a mysql replica set & service. I specify mysql v5.6 in the yaml file for the replica set.

After viewing the log for the pod, it looks like it is successful. So then I

```
kubectl run -it --rm --image=mysql --restart=Never mysql-client -- bash
mysql -h mysql -p 3306 -u root
```

It prompts me for the password and then I get this error:

```
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '10.1.0.17' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

Apparently MySQL has a feature where it does not allow remote connections by default and I have to change the configuration files and I don't know how to do that inside a yaml file. Below is my YAML. How do I change it to allow remote connections?

Thanks

Siegfried

```
cat <<END-OF-FILE | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: mysql
  # labels so that we can bind a Service to this Pod
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tododata
        image: mysql:5.6
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 1
            memory: 2Gi
        env:
        # Environment variables are not a best practice for security,
        # but we're using them here for brevity in the example.
        # See Chapter 11 for better options.
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: some-password-here
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 3306
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        volumeMounts:
          - name: tododata
            # /var/lib/mysql is where MySQL stores its databases
            mountPath: "/var/lib/mysql"
      volumes:
      - name: tododata
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: tododata
END-OF-FILE
```

**Sat Oct 24 2020 3PM EDT Update: Try Bitnami MySQL**

I like Ben's idea of [using bitnami mysql](https://bitnami.com/stack/mysql/helm) because then I don't have to create my own custom docker image. However, when using bitnami and trying to connect to they mysql server I get

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'my-release-mysql.default.svc.cluster.local' (111)
```

This happens after I successfully get a bash shell with this command:

```
kubectl run my-release-mysql-client --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' --image  docker.io/bitnami/mysql:8.0.22-debian-10-r0 --namespace default --command -- bash
```

Then, as per the instructions, I do this and get the HY000 error above.

```
mysql -h my-release-mysql.default.svc.cluster.local -uroot -p
```

***Wed Nov 04 2020 Update:***

Thanks Ben.. Yes -- I had already tried that on Oct 24 (approx) and when I do a `k describe pod` I get `mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)' Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!`.

Of course, when I run the mysql client as described in the nicely generated instructions, the client cannot connect because mysqld has died.

This is after having deleted the pvcs and stss  and doing `helm delete my-release` prior to reinstalling via helm.

Unfortunately, when I tried this the first time (a couple of weeks ago) I did not set the root password and used the default generated password and I think it is still trying to use that.

This did work on azure kubernetes after having created a fresh azure kubernetes cluster.  How can I reset my kubernetes cluster in my docker for desktop windows? I tried google searching and no luck so far.

Thanks
Siegfried

Comment: Have you seen https://serverfault.com/questions/688513/cant-access-mysql-docker-container-from-the-host. Also, I've had good luck with https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mysql

Comment: Can anyone point me to an existing github or (better yet) dockerhub image that has the binding-address already set to 0.0.0.0 so I can log in from outside the kubernetes cluster?

Comment: where are you running that mysql command? run `kubectl get services` to see what port the service is running on. Then run `mysql -h localhost -uroot -p <port-number>`

Comment: The other thing is with kubernetes make sure you are running a service that connects to the deployment

Comment: Please elaborate on your last comment. Lately I've been using ```helm install my-release bitnami/mysql``` and there is no deployment. Is this a problem? If I were to return to my earlier strategy of following the book Kubernetes Up And Running 2nd Ed, how would I confirm the connection between service and deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of help from the bitnami folks, I learned that my spinning disks on my 4 year old notebook computer are kinda slow (now why this is a problem with Bitnami MySQL and not Bitnami PostreSQL is a mystery).

This works for me:

```
helm install my-mysql bitnami/mysql \
  --set image.debug=true \
  --set primary.persistence.enabled=false,secondary.persistence.enabled=false \
  --set primary.readinessProbe.enabled=false,primary.livenessProbe.enabled=false \
  --set secondary.readinessProbe.enabled=false,secondary.livenessProbe.enabled=false
```

This turns off the peristent volumes so the data is lost when the pod dies.

Yes this is useful for me for development purposes and no one should be using Docker For Desktop/Kubernetes for production anyway... I just need to populate a tiny database and test my queries and if I need to repopulate database every time I reboot, well, that is not a big problem.

So maybe I need to get a new notebook computer? The price of notebook computers with 4TB of spinning disk space has gone up in the last couple of years.... And I cannot find any SSD drives of that size so even if I purchased a new replacement with spinning disks I might have the same problem? Hmm....

Thanks everyone for your help!

Siegfried

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work just fine for me on windows. Complete the following steps:

```
helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
helm install my-release --set root.password=awesomePassword bitnami/mysql
```

This is all you need to run the mysql instance. It does not makes a few services and a statefulset.  Then, to connect to it, you

1. Either have to be in another another kubernetes container. Without this, you will not find the dns record for `my-release-mysql.default.svc.cluster.local`

   ```
   run my-release-mysql-client --rm --tty -i  --image  docker.io/bitnami/mysql:8.0.22-debian-10-r0 --namespace default --command -- bash

   mysql -h my-release-mysql.default.svc.cluster.local -uroot -p my_database
   ```

   For the password, it should be 'awesomePassword'
2. Port forward the service to your local machine.

   ```
   kubectl port-forward svc/my-release-mysql 3306:3306
   ```

As a note, a bitnami container will have issues if you kill it and restart it with only your helm commands and the password is not set. The persistent volume claim will usually stick around - so you would need to set the password to the old password. If you do not specify the password, you can get the password by running the commands bitnami tells you about.

> NAME: my-release
>
> LAST DEPLOYED: Thu Oct 29 20:39:23 2020
>
> NAMESPACE: default
>
> STATUS: deployed
>
> REVISION: 1
>
> TEST SUITE: None
>
> NOTES: Please be patient while the chart is being deployed
>
> Tip:
>
> Watch the deployment status using the command: kubectl get pods -w
> --namespace default
>
> Services:
>
> echo Master: my-release-mysql.default.svc.cluster.local:3306   echo
> Slave:  my-release-mysql-slave.default.svc.cluster.local:3306
>
> Administrator credentials:
>
> echo Username: root   echo Password : $(kubectl get secret
> --namespace default my-release-mysql -o jsonpath="{.data.mysql-root-password}" | base64 --decode)
>
> To connect to your database:
>
> 1. Run a pod that you can use as a client:
>
>    kubectl run my-release-mysql-client --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' --image  docker.io/bitnami/mysql:8.0.22-debian-10-r0 --namespace default --command -- bash
> 2. To connect to master service (read/write):
>
>    mysql -h my-release-mysql.default.svc.cluster.local -uroot -p my_database
> 3. To connect to slave service (read-only):
>
>    mysql -h my-release-mysql-slave.default.svc.cluster.local -uroot -p my_database
>
> To upgrade this helm chart:
>
> 1. Obtain the password as described on the 'Administrator credentials' section and set the 'root.password' parameter as shown
>    below:
>
>    ROOT_PASSWORD=$(kubectl get secret --namespace default my-release-mysql -o jsonpath="{.data.mysql-root-password}" | base64
>    --decode)
>    helm upgrade my-release bitnami/mysql --set root.password=$ROOT_PASSWORD

Comment: It's not working, and it's not working with root.password, needs auth.password... also when u are connected to the mysql pod, u can't connect, error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql.default.svc.cluster.local:3306'